# ¿Como puedo crear un boton en php para que realize las funciones de mi Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola que tal soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación, estoy trabajando con PHP, en específico estoy creando un plugin para WordPress. Lo que estoy haciendo es una tabla de amortización, y eso ya lo realice, solo que aparece automáticamente atrás de mi contenido de mi página en WordPress, y para solucionarlo se me ocurre crear un botón que al momento de darle click se abra una pestaña nueva en el navegador y cree la tabla de amortización. 
Agradecería mucho que me ayudaran pues recalco que soy nuevo en esto y no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo. 
Aquí les dejo el código que he hecho hasta el momento en mi plugin.

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: 
Plugin URI:
Description: 
Version: 
Author: 
Author URI:
Licence:
*/

function Corrida_Auto($atts){
  $args = shortcode_atts( array(
    'PrecioAuto' => '450000',
    'PlazoDeLaVenta' => '12',
    'PorcenajeFijoAuto' => '1.2'

  ), $atts);
  $U_PrecioAuto = $args["PrecioAuto"];
  $U_PlazoDeLaVenta = $args["PlazoDeLaVenta"];
  $U_PorcenajeFijoAuto = $args["PorcenajeFijoAuto"];
  echo "<div align='center'>Precio del auto es:". " " . $U_PrecioAuto ."</div><br>";

  //OPERACION
  $U_PorcenajeFijoAuto = ($U_PorcenajeFijoAuto/100)/12;
  $m=($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto*(pow((1+$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),($U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1))))/((pow((1+$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),($U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1)))-1);

  echo "<br>";
  echo "<div align='center'>Cuota a pagar mensualmente: ".$m."</div><br>";
  echo "<hr>";

echo "<div align='center'><table border=2></div><br>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<div align='center'><th>MES</th></div><br>";
  echo "<div align='center'><th>INTERESES</th></div><br>";
  echo "<div align='center'><th>AMORTIZACION</th></div><br>";
  echo "<div align='center'><th>CAPITAL PENDIENTE</th></div><br>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
for ($i=1; $i <= $U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1; $i++) {
echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td align=center>".$i."</td>";
 $totalint=1;
 $totalint=$totalint+($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto);
 echo "<td align=center>".number_format($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto,2,".",",")."</td>";
 echo "<td align=center>".number_format($m-($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),2,".",",")."</td>";

 $U_PrecioAuto=$U_PrecioAuto-($m-($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto));
 if ($U_PrecioAuto<0)
 {
   echo "<td align=center>0</td>";
 }else{
   echo "<td align=center>".number_format($U_PrecioAuto,2,".",",")."</td>";
 }
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<hr>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<div align='center'>Pago total de intereses: ".$totalint."</div><br>";
}

add_shortcode( "Corrida_Auto", "Corrida_Auto" )
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo si no entendí mal, necesitas un nuevo menú que te lleve al formulario que creaste si es así te paso el siguiente código con los comentarios

```
<?php
 /**
 * @package Corrida_Auto
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
 /*
 Plugin Name: Corrida_Auto
 Plugin URI: 
 Description: 
 Author: 
 Version: 1.0.0
 Author URI: 
 */

 /* Gancho para crear un nuevo item en el menu, va a ejecutar la funcion 
 "crear_menu_corridaAuto" */
 add_action("admin_menu", "crear_menu_corridaAuto");

 /* Crea un nuevo item dentro del menu de WP */
 function crear_menu_corridaAuto() {
 /**
 * Parametro 1: Nombre que se va a mostrar en la pagina
 * Paremetro 2: Nombre para mostrar dentro del menu
 * Parametro 3: Los permisos que tiene que tener el usuario para poder ingresar al 
  menu
 * Parametro 4: Slug del nuevo item
 * Parametro 5: Funcion que se llama al darle click al nuevo item.
 */
 add_menu_page('Corrida auto', 'Ver corrida auto', 'manage_options', 'Corrida_Auto', 
 'Corrida_Auto');
 }
 /* Tu funcion. */
 function Corrida_Auto($atts){
 $args = shortcode_atts( array(
  'PrecioAuto' => '450000',
  'PlazoDeLaVenta' => '12',
  'PorcenajeFijoAuto' => '1.2'

  ), $atts);
  $U_PrecioAuto = $args["PrecioAuto"];
 $U_PlazoDeLaVenta = $args["PlazoDeLaVenta"];
 $U_PorcenajeFijoAuto = $args["PorcenajeFijoAuto"];
 echo "<div align='center'>Precio del auto es:". " " . $U_PrecioAuto ."</div><br>";

//OPERACION
$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto = ($U_PorcenajeFijoAuto/100)/12;
$m=($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto*(pow((1+$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),($U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1))))/((pow((1+$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),($U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1)))-1);

echo "<br>";
echo "<div align='center'>Cuota a pagar mensualmente: ".$m."</div><br>";
echo "<hr>";

echo "<div align='center'><table border=2></div><br>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<div align='center'><th>MES</th></div><br>";
echo "<div align='center'><th>INTERESES</th></div><br>";
echo "<div align='center'><th>AMORTIZACION</th></div><br>";
echo "<div align='center'><th>CAPITAL PENDIENTE</th></div><br>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
for ($i=1; $i <= $U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center>".$i."</td>";
    $totalint=1;
    $totalint=$totalint+($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto);
    echo "<td align=center>".number_format($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto,2,".",",")."</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>".number_format($m-($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),2,".",",")."</td>";

$U_PrecioAuto=$U_PrecioAuto-($m-($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto));
if ($U_PrecioAuto<0)
{
    echo "<td align=center>0</td>";
}else{
    echo "<td align=center>".number_format($U_PrecioAuto,2,".",",")."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<hr>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div align='center'>Pago total de intereses: ".$totalint."</div><br>";
```

}

Te dejo la documentación oficial de la función [ir](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)